# Bazel environment variables in build rules

Tags: windows, environment-variables, bazel, build-system

I want to refer to a DirectX SDK in the `BUILD` file. The problem is that (as far as I understand) Bazel supports passing environment variables only through `--action_env=DXSDK_DIR` argument for Bazel and it is meant to be used in actions, which must be defined in a plugin (`.bzl` file).

Is there any easier way to refer to the environment variable by using it as Make variable (`includes = [ "$(DXSDK_DIR)/Include" ]`) or do I need to write a plugin?

Answer (score 8):

In principle you need a `cc_library` rule whose `hdrs` attribute globs the DirectX headers. For that you need to pretend that the DX SDK is part of your source tree. Bazel offers "repository rules" for that purpose.

### 1. Create a repository rule for the DirectX SDK

Depending on whether the SDK's location is known or needs to be discovered, you have two options.

#### a. Fixed SDK location

You can use this approach if you don't need to read any environment variables, run any binaries, or query the registry to find where the SDK is. This is the case if everyone who builds your rules will install the SDK to the same location.

Just add a [`new_local_repository`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#new_local_repository) rule to your `WORKSPACE` file, point the rule's `path` at the SDK's directory and write a simple `build_file_content` for it.

Example:

```
new_local_repository(
    name = "directx_sdk",
    path = "c:/program files/directx/sdk/includes",
    build_file_contents = """
cc_library(
    name = "sdk",
    hdrs = glob(["**/*.h"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
""")
```

This rule creates the `@directx_sdk` repository with one rule in its root package, `@directx_sdk//:sdk`.

#### b. SDK discovery

You need to follow this approach if you need to read environment variables, run binaries, or query the registry to find where the SDK is.

Instead of using a `new_local_repository` rule, you need to implement your own. [More info and examples are here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43936381/7778502)

Key points:

- if your repository rule needs to read environment variables, add them to the list `repository_rule(environ)`, e.g. `repository_rule(..., environ = ["DXSDK_DIR"])`
- if you need to run some binaries that tell you where the SDK is, use [`repository_ctx.execute`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#execute). You can use [`repository_ctx.which`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#which) to find binaries on the `PATH`.
- if you need to do registry queries, use [`repository_ctx.execute`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#execute) with `reg.exe /query <args>`

### 2. Depend on the SDK's `cc_library`

In your project, just depend on the SDK's library as if it was an ordinary `cc_library`:

```
cc_library(
    name = "render",
    ...
    deps = [
        ...
        "@directx_sdk//:sdk",
    ],
)
```

Comment: "if your repository rule needs to read environment variables, add them to the list".

Do you happen to know how to do that within a custom implementation?
Couldn't find a way to access the environment variables from the `repository_ctx`

Comment: Found the answer to my own question following [this link](https://kchodorow.com/2016/06/17/using-environment-variables-in-skylark-repository-rules): you can use `ctx.os.environ`