# How to use pylint as a bazel run/build command?

Tags: python, bazel, pylint

I have seen some threads that show me how to use Pylint as a test inside bazel.
However, I want to use Pylint with one of the following commands:

bazel run  --config=pylint
or
bazel build  --config=pylint

What would be the best strategy here?
In the future, I will use the same strategy to also implement black and buildifier as bazel run  --config=black and bazel run  --config=buildifier
So I want to standarize it, if possible.

I am already able to run Pylint through a test, but this is not what I want.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is very clearly explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303847/best-way-to-configure-pylint-with-bazel)

Comment: I don't want to run it as a test. I want to have a command that runs the pylint itself inside bazel. The same way as you use pylint outside bazel.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/main/docs/pip.md#pip_parse). You have to setup an `alias()` rule that points to the correct `entry_point()`:

```
load("@pip_deps//:requirements.bzl", "entry_point")

alias(
    name = "pylint",
    actual = entry_point("pylint"),
)
```

This should then be executable via `bazel run :pylint`.